# Does moving data between memory and secondary storage device need to go through cpu registers?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, external-hard-drive

In the memory/storage hierarchy: cpu register - cpu cache - main memory - secondary storage device,
does copying or moving data between storages at some levels pass the storage at some higher level, or without passing any third party? Specifically:

1. Does copying or moving data between locations inside the main memory pass cpu registers or some other storage device?
2. Does copying or moving data between the main memory and the internal or external hard drive pass cpu registers or some other storage device?
3. Does copying or moving data between different locations in the internal hard drive pass the main memory or some other storage device?
4. Does copying or moving data between the internal hard drive or an external flash drives pass the main memory or some other storage device?
5. Does copying or moving data between the  external hard drive and flash drive pass the main memory or some other storage device?

Thanks.

Comment: There are three methods of data transfer between memory and a peripheral.  PIO - programmed I/O using a CPU register.  DMA - transfer by the DMA controller to relieve the CPU of this task.  Third-party DMA or Bus Mastering - similar to DMA but using the controller of a peripheral.

Comment: Thanks. How about within main memory,   within a hard drive, and between an internal hard drive and an external hard drive?

Comment: 1. It depends on the programmer. You can do memory-to-memory copies via registers but this is slow. Or you can use the block memory move instructions, in which case the *data* does not go through the registers, but registers are involved in the instructions. 2. No, nothing else is involved. All modern HDs will use DMA. The CPU registers will be involved in the instructions that set up the DMA transfer but the actual data doesn't go through them. 3, 4, 5: All of these involve DMA from the source device to RAM and then to the target device - see point 2.

Comment: (Too long? Hah!)

Comment: btw, you will from time to time hear claims that some storage interface like SCSI (in any of its variations) or 1394 allows "devices to talk directly to each other". The implication is that if you were copying a file from, say, one SCSI disk to another, the data would just move over the SCSI bus and not have to go through host memory at all. That isn't true. In practice, SCSI and 1394 hard drives, tape drives, etc., are never built with the ability to initiate commands. They can only respond to commands from initiators. And the only initiators are the controllers in the host systems.

Comment: I just nominated this for re-opening. The closer stated "good answers would be too long", but between sawdust and my answers we have answered it in two comments, plus one more with additional info. So, please consider opening so we can post the answer as an actual answer.